# DRY with the Decorator pattern in PHP 5.3

Tags: php, design-patterns

I'm trying to write a Decorator type class that will cache results to whatever (Starting out with memecache). Each method needs to check the cache $this->cache->get($key) and if not found call the real method $this->real->getExpensiveInfo01($param1, $param2, $param3) then set it $this->cache->set($key, $expensiveInfo). So now each method has this boilerplate code;

```
class ExpensiveCache implements ExpensiveInterface
{
  public function getExpensiveInfo01($param1, $param2, $param3)
  {
     $key = __FUNCTION__ . $param1 . $param2 . $param3;
     $rtn = $this->cache->get($key);
     if ($rtn === false) {
        $rtn = $this->expensive->getExpensiveInfo01($param1, $param2, $param3);
        $cacheStatus = $this->cache->set($key, $rtn);
    }
    return $rtn;
  }
  public function getExpensiveInfo02($param1, $param2)
  {
     $key = __FUNCTION__ . $param1 . $param2;
     $rtn = $this->cache->get($key);
     if ($rtn === false) {
        $rtn = $this->expensive->getExpensiveInfo02($param1, $param2);
        $cacheStatus = $this->cache->set($key, $rtn);
    }
    return $rtn;
  }
  public function getExpensiveInfo03($param1, $param2)
  {
     $key = __FUNCTION__ . $param1 . $param2;
     $rtn = $this->cache->get($key);
     if ($rtn === false) {
        $rtn = $this->expensive->getExpensiveInfo03($param1, $param2);
        $cacheStatus = $this->cache->set($key, $rtn);
    }
    return $rtn;
  }
}
```

is there anyway in PHP5.3 (Damn you CentOS) to reduce the boiler plate code into one private method call.

Comment: Please don't hate on CentOS, it's a sexy fox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not private, but public [__call](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.call)

```
class ExpensiveCache implements ExpensiveInterface {
    public function __call($name, $arguments) {
        $key = $name.implode('', $arguments);
        $rtn = $this->cache->get($key);
        if ($rtn === false) {
            $rtn = call_user_func_array(array($this->expensive, $name), $arguments);
            $cacheStatus = $this->cache->set($key, $rtn);
        }
        return $rtn;
    }
}
```

(maybe add some checks if $this->expensive->$name is callable)

Comment: Forgot all about the __call thanks. I still had to wrap the call with implemented Interface methods but much more reasonable this way.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like that:

```
private function getCacheKey(array $args)
{
    return implode('', $args);
}

private function getExpensiveInfo()
{
    $args = func_get_args();
    $key = $this->getCacheKey($args);
    if (($value = $this->cache->get($key)) === false) {
        $value = call_user_func_array(array($this->expensive, __FUNCTION__), $args);
        $this->cache->set($key, $value);
    }

    return $value;
}
```